# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException error

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

I have a webmethod that will call a `SaveEmployee()` function.

`WebMethod` function as following:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool UpdateEmployee(DataSet dSet)  
{
  try
  {
     COMAccess.Employee.SaveEmployee(Registry.GetDatabaseConnection(),dSet)
  } 
  catch (Exception ex) 
  {
    Log(ex.InnerException.ToString()
  }
}
```

and `SaveEmployee()` function is as following:

```
public static bool SaveEmployee(string connection, DataSet dSet)
{
  bool rtnVal = false;
  SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
  conn.Open();
  SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
  SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
  command.Connection = conn;
  command.Transaction = tran;
  command.CommandTimeout = 320;
  command.CommandText = "SP_UPDATE_EMPLOYEE";
  command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  try 
  {
     foreach(System.Data.DataRow dRow in dSet.Tables["Employee"].Rows)
     {
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dRow["EmployeeID"];
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dRow["EmployeeName"];
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        command.Parameters.Clear();             
     }
     tran.Commit();
     myVal = true;    
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     tran.Rollback();
     myVal = false;
  }
     return myVal;
  }
```

Anyway, I got the following `InnerException` message:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIPacketGetConnection(IntPtr packet)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ProcessSniPacket(IntPtr packet, UInt32 error)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at COMAccess.Employee.SaveEmployee(String connection, DataSet dSet)
```

I have no clue what is happening. can someone please enlighten me? thanks

Comment: Does it happen all the time or every now and then?

Comment: Can you check if the current thread is a background thread?

Comment: Hi there, yes it happens all the time .. and i don't see any background thread

Comment: Does it happen immediately? Or after x seconds?

Comment: Every code runs on a thread. Every thread can be a background thread. Please check: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground`.

Comment: hi there, it happen after like 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

In your code your are setting the [`CommandTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) property for the `320` seconds:

```
command.CommandTimeout = 320;
```

However, your connection still has default timeout equal to `30` seconds, and after that time elapsed your inner thread for the command is being canceled as long-running.

You have to set a [`ConnectionTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) property for the connection, like this:

```
connection.ConnectionTimeout = 320;
```

Comment: I've set the connectiontimeout to 320 from the connectionstring, no avail :(